# How can I do access control via an SQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, access-control

I'm trying to create an access control system.

Here's a stripped down example of what the table I'm trying to control access to looks like:

```
things table:
id   group_id   name
1    1          thing 1
2    1          thing 2
3    1          thing 3
4    1          thing 4
5    2          thing 5
```

And the access control table looks like this:

```
access table:
user_id  type   object_id  access
1        group  1          50
1        thing  1          10
1        thing  2          100
```

Access can be granted either by specifying the id of the 'thing' directly, or granted for an entire group of things by specifying a group id. In the above example, user 1 has been granted an access level of 50 to group 1, which should apply unless there are any other rules granting more specific access to an individual thing.

I need a query that returns a list of things (ids only is okay) along with the access level for a specific user. So using the example above I'd want something like this for user id 1:

```
desired result:
thing_id   access
1          10
2          100
3          50   (things 3 and 4 have no specific access rule,
4          50   so this '50' is from the group rule)
5               (thing 5 has no rules at all, so although I 
                still want it in the output, there's no access
        level for it)
```

The closest I can come up with is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM things 
LEFT JOIN access ON 
    user_id = 1
    AND (
        (access.type = 'group' AND access.object_id = things.group_id)
        OR (access.type = 'thing' AND access.object_id = things.id)
    )
```

But that returns multiple rows, when I only want one for each row in the 'things' table. I'm not sure how to get down to a single row for each 'thing', or how to prioritise 'thing' rules over 'group' rules.

If it helps, the database I'm using is PostgreSQL.

Please feel free to leave a comment if there's any information I've missed out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the Postgres SQL dialect, but maybe something like:

```
select thing.*, coalesce ( ( select access
                             from   access
                             where  userid = 1
                             and    type = 'thing'
                             and    object_id = thing.id
                           ),
                           ( select access
                             from   access
                             where  userid = 1
                             and    type = 'group'
                             and    object_id = thing.group_id
                           )
                         )
from things
```

Incidentally, I don't like the design.  I would prefer the access table to be split into two:

```
thing_access (user_id, thing_id, access)
group_access (user_id, group_id, access)
```

My query then becomes:

```
select thing.*, coalesce ( ( select access
                             from   thing_access
                             where  userid = 1
                             and    thing_id = thing.id
                           ),
                           ( select access
                             from   group_access
                             where  userid = 1
                             and    group_id = thing.group_id
                           )
                         )
from things
```

I prefer this because foreign keys can now be used in the access tables.

Comment: Ooh that's an interesting solution. Seems to work on my limited example data, I'll have a go on some real data and see how it fares. For the record, I agree the table design is a bit nasty. I am, unfortunately, stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I just read a paper last night on this.  It has some ideas on how to do this.  If you can't  use the link on the title try using Google Scholar on [Limiting Disclosure in Hippocratic Databases.](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1316701)

Answer (score 1):

While there are several good answers, the most efficient would probably be something like this:

```
SELECT things.id, things.group_id, things.name, max(access) 
FROM things 
LEFT JOIN access ON 
        user_id = 1 
        AND (
                (access.type = 'group' AND access.object_id = things.group_id)
                OR (access.type = 'thing' AND access.object_id = things.id)
        )
group by things.id, things.group_id, things.name
```

Which simply uses summarization added to you query to get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Tony:

Not a bad solution, I like it, seems to work. Here's your query after minor tweaking:

```
SELECT 
    things.*, 
    coalesce ( 
        (   SELECT access 
            FROM access 
            WHERE user_id = 1 
                AND type = 'thing' 
                AND object_id = things.id
        ), 
        (   SELECT access 
            FROM access 
            WHERE user_id = 1 
                AND type = 'group' 
                AND object_id = things.group_id 
        ) 
    ) AS access
    FROM things;
```

And the results look correct:

```
 id | group_id |  name   | access 
----+----------+---------+--------
  1 |        1 | thing 1 |     10
  2 |        1 | thing 2 |    100
  3 |        1 | thing 3 |     50
  4 |        1 | thing 4 |     50
  5 |        2 | thing 5 |
```

I do *completely* take the point about it not being an ideal schema. However, I am stuck with it to some extent.

---

Josef:

Your solution is very similar to the stuff I was playing with, and my instincts (such as they are) tell me that it should be possible to do it that way. Unfortunately it doesn't produce completely correct results:

```
 id | group_id |  name   | max 
----+----------+---------+-----
  1 |        1 | thing 1 |  50
  2 |        1 | thing 2 | 100
  3 |        1 | thing 3 |  50
  4 |        1 | thing 4 |  50
  5 |        2 | thing 5 |
```

The access level for 'thing 1' has taken the higher 'group' access value, rather than the more specific 'thing' access value of 10, which is what I'm after. I don't think there's a way to fix that within a `GROUP BY`, but if anyone has any suggestions I'm more than happy to be proven incorrect on that point.